# Can I pop a bootstrap Modal inside an iFrame over the main window?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, modal-dialog, cross-domain

I'm not sure this is possible given cross domain security, but I need to have an iFrame inside existing websites that displays a button and hidden modal from a remote server (different domain)

I can get this to work but the modal shows inside the iFrame. I want it to be across the main (parent) window. Is this at all possible?

I have done this in the main page:

```
<iframe src="http://some_server/embed/button/864" style="
border: none;"></iframe>
```

the remote site is a rails server

it returns this erb/html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-default">Get a Quote</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
  modal content
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is this at all possible or is this not allowed??

Comment: Can you modify parent window code? Or you have access only to child window?

Comment: For good reason, the browser isn't going to let you position content from a frame anywhere outside of the frame.

Comment: @xAqweRx Hi, yes, I can change the parent window code, but would like to add as little code as possible to the parent.

Comment: @bobomoreno it could be done, but it is not very good idea to do this in that way. You can look at JS methods - window.postMessage but I'd rather not do this.